# Getting wrong user location

Tags: ios, swift

Hi there I have just started learning swift ios-9.
I am using following code to get user's current location but it's getting location

```
<+37.78583400,-122.40641700> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 1/8/16, 3:38:10 PM Greenwich Mean Time
```

In output and not showing my current location on map.

Swift Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    var manager:CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print(locations[0])

        //userLocation - there is no need for casting, because we are now using CLLocation object

        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]
        let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
        let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
        let latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
        let lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)
        let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(location, span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I have also linked CoreLocation.framawork to my project.
As I have just started learning this I don't have a developer licence from apple.

Comment: r u testing this on device or on simulator?

Comment: did u set the show user location setting enabled ?

Comment: I am testing on simulator, how do i enable user location setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simulate the current location in the simulator. You can only pass the coordinates and simulator will simulate those coordinates in the map.

TO simulate a custom location, select the simulator, and select debug option from menu, and select location, and select custom location.

[image]

and enter your custom location to simulate it:

[image]

To enable the shouserLocation stting, go to storyboard, and select your map view,and in the attributes inspector select the shwo user location option.

[image]

**Note**: Your current location can only be show on a real device .